# Inline Unordered List

Tags: css

```
#results {
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
list-style-type:none;
}
#results li {display: inline;}
#results li a {
float:left;
 }
```

I would like the results division to list multiple items per line, but it looks like I am getting only 1 item per line with this code.

Comment: "results division"? Does that mean `#results` is a div? This should work. So it likely has to do with some of the other CSS or HTML. Can you show us a minimal test case (HTML+CSS)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the `ul` `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` and the `li` a `width: 49%` for example (to leave some room for a `margin-right`).

```
#results {
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
list-style-type:none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#results li {
display: block;
float:left;
width: 49%;  /* Or whatever */
margin-right: 1%;  /* Or whatever */
}
#results li a {

 }
```

Comment: @chief sorry, I used the wrong block. I corrected it, should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I will also add that I have another div within the results ul.  It seems when I remove this inner division the results list horizontally.

```
<ul id="results">

<% for user in @users -%>
 <li>
<div id="short_profile">
 <.... ruby code ...>
 </div>
 </li>
 <% end -%>
 </ul>
```

Comment: This should be put as an edit to your question, not as an answer.